# What does 'Clear Origin' (Alt-O) do in the 3d view?

Tags: 3d-view, shortcut

What does 'Clear Origin' (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>O</kbd>) do? Someone mentioned it on our general chat.

Comment: It does different things, it depends on the mode (clear origin in object mode, toggle proportional editing connected/disabled in edit mode).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Select a child object of a parent, and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> (that is the letter O). It will move the child to the parent, while still keeping the parent relationship intact. The name Blender uses is "clear its origin".

[image: animated gif showing the parenting and clearing the child's origin]

Comment: Can the same be done with rotation?

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> is ambiguous as it performs a different action depending on which view area you are in. In the 3d view, you can use it to clear the object origin, in the text editor, use it to open a text block, in the sequencer it clears strip offsets etc.

To see the full list, search by *Key-Binding* for *Alt O* under *Input* in user preferences.

Comment: In edit mode it enables proportional editing(connected)