# Why are the coordinates of a child object the same after clear location to parent (Alt-O)?

Tags: transforms, parent, coordinates

When I have a child object with the position 0 0 0

[image: child at 0 0 0]

[image: display of child objects position]

And we drag it a bit with the red arrow:

[image: dragged child]

we see that the transform also will change:

[image: different values for location]

Now if I press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> the child will move back to the parent origin:

[image: The child is back]

But the transform will not change.

[image: The location is the same for some reason]

Why not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does 'Clear Origin' (Alt-O) do in the 3d view?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26111/what-does-clear-origin-alt-o-do-in-the-3d-view)

Comment: I disagree about this question being a duplicate of the linked to question. I have already seen that posting, before I was placing my question. It did not make this particular coordinate confusion any clearer.

Comment: What don't you understand from the other post? Alt + O moves the object back to the parent origin without changing the transform. Are you looking for Alt + G?

Comment: How is an object moved without changing the transform?

Comment: Transform location is not a global location value. You can apply location of an object at any point with Ctrl + A and the transform will be 0,0,0. Transform location is only by default relative to grid origin.

Comment: So were can I see the global location?

Comment: Last comment or we can move to chat. Use Shift + S "Cursor to selected" and then look at the 3D cursor position. (Scroll down in the "N" menu)